# !preg_match for email checking

Tags: preg-match, email-validation

I have this command to check for valid email address.  I just found out that when I try to add this to our email server (all email requests off this form are local email addresses), the email server does not allow a numeric character to start the email address/username.  I have read through all the documentation for the command preg_match and cannot find how to make it fail if it starts with a numeric in the first character location.  I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
if (!preg_match("(^[-\w\.]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$)i", $in_email))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one;

```
/^[^0-9][_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/
```

And use as follows

```
$regex = '/^[^0-9][_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';

if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
    // Valid email
} else { 
    // Invalid email
}
```

Comment: I added this and it makes it so that no numbers are allowed at all.  I want numbers to be used if they want - just not in the first character locations.

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much!  I have been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: If you want to get an answer for your future questions, you should accept the answers as correct if it helps you to figure it out. So, please review the answer and click the check icon to the left to accept.

Comment: This will allow an email that begins with a space or `@` or any character that is not a digit.

Answer (score 2):

In php you can use following code with php filter_var function which return a boolean after filtering the variable with a specified filter condition.

```
 if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        { 
        //valid email
        }
        else{
        //INVALID EMAIL
        }
```

The function filter_var will return true if email is in correct format otherwise false.

Answer (score 0):

If we have domains without dots this answers does not work. For this case I changed from:

`/^[^0-9][_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/`

To:

`/^[^0-9][_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]{2,})+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})*$/`

**Update:** The user @Toto saw correctly one problem with regex that can start with any chars instead off numeric. And example like: `@-----.--.---.----@--` was validate. So I changed `/^[^0-9]` for `/^[a-z]` and now is correct:

`/^[a-z][_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]{2,})+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})*$/`

And work for these use cases:

- user@domain
- aa@aa
- aa@aa.aa
- aa.aa@aa

Comment: This is matching `@-----.--.---.----@--` for example, not sure it's a valid email address! Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Hey Otavio! Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you've already received a satisfactory answer, but it could be helpful for other people if you were able to rephrase your questions. Thousands of people search Google for similar problems and having a clearly worded question can help them land here, so they can avoid the same pains that you have to go through. Would you mind clarifying the question, please?

Comment: @BradCypert the answer marked as correct from the user 'tolga-akyüs' don't work if domain don't have dots. For example: my@mail.com is valid using from him regex, but didn't validate if you have email like: my@domain . So, I used the regex from his answer and change it to one that validate domains with or without dots. Today 2021 we have domains without dots.

Comment: @Toto this your example is impossible to validate using my regex because the regex start with /^[^0-9][_a-z0-9-]+ that tell us exactly: start char of string don't be a numeric [^0-9] and must be _ or a-z or 0-9 one or more chars like this in this regex's part [_a-z0-9-]+. Besides that, it's only possible one @ char. I tried a lot of solutions here in Stack but for domains without dots all that I tried failed. So, I don't know if I tried all you showed here to me.

Comment: [here is the proof](https://regex101.com/r/CUOong/1) that your regex matches (for example) `@-----.--.---.----@--`

Comment: @Toto you is correct! I tried by myself your use case and change it `/^[^0-9]` to `/^[a-z]` and now this didn't validate `@-----.--.---.----@--`. I'll update my post and put this information. Thanks.